# How could a solar eclipse cause my light bulb to explode?

Tags: electricity, solar-system, eclipse

Any explanation to this? as it happened right during the phase of eclipse or is it just coincident?

I had just finished my breakfast and on the way to go outside to watch the eclipse and before it happened the bulb explodes.

Malaysia time 8.19am 1 hour ago

Comment: Incandescent light bulbs frequently fail the instant you turn them on (or off). That's when they undergo the greatest thermal stresses. Did you turn the light on (because it was getting dark) or off (because you were going outside) just at that time?

Comment: @DavidHammen  It was mentioned that he turned it off or on. Only that it was not in the off position unless specified the presumption is that it was resting in the on position. A bulb exploding in the off position would be worth mentioning.

Answer (score 4):

If one googles "probability of an exploding light bulb" one sees that it is not so rare, so coincidence will be the first hypothesis.

To establish it as an observation correlated with the eclipse, one should gather "exploding bulbs" at the path of the eclipse, and at a path parallel outside the eclipse's path, in statistically significant numbers to show a correlation .

If a statistically significant correlation appears then one should examine "exploding lightbulbs" at beginning of night ( street lights an home lights might make surges ) and at dark  etc , i.e. human factors for surges, dependent on need of electricity, before thinking of a direct sun influence.

A direct sun influence seems also improbable as the moon would also be shadowing any coincident [coronal mass ejection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronal_mass_ejection) more than in parallel unshadowed by eclipse paths.

Comment: I did consider the human factor of everyone turning their lights more rapidly then compared to the slower sunset.

Comment: @Jen yes, you gave one of the possible reasons http://www.sollatek.com/voltage-surges-causes-and-control/